# Is it possible to call the Python serial library as a function in an imported module when communicating with an Arduino?

Tags: python, arduino, pyserial

I am writing a program to communicate between my laptop (Python) and an Arduino. The Arduino code, with which I have no issue, reads the serial data form my laptop and returns a reply. The code below works when I am calling the function which starts the serial communication from within the same file. However, when I import the file as a module in another file, using lal the same commands, it does not work!

To provide more detail, although Python thinks it has connected and even prints out the correct port number, it does not really connect. I know this because in the scenario that does work, when the serial communication is open, the Arduino IDE cannot speak to the Arduino as the Arduino is busy. However in the scenario which is not working, even after Python thinks it has opened serial communication, the Arduino IDE can still communicate with the Arduino.

**Is there a way to pass the ser variable when called from a function in an imported module?**

```
def connect():
for n in range(0,21):
    try:
        ser = serial.Serial('COM'+str(n), 115200 ,timeout=0.1) 
        status=1
        port=n
        return ser,port,status
    except:
        pass
    time.sleep(0.05)
return 0, 0, 0


if __name__ == "__main__":
    ser,port,status=connect()
    n=0
    while n<3:
        num = input("Enter a word: ") # Taking input from user
        ser.write(bytes(num, 'utf-8'))
        time.sleep(0.05)
        data = ser.readline()
        print(data) # printing the value
        n+=1
    ser.close()
    print('closed')
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the reason my code was not working! Notice in the code I posted, I use the input function to get a user input which is sent to the Arduino. This effectively results in a delay. In the scenario that was not working, I did not use the input function and so my code went straight from serial.serial to serial.write. The Arduino runs at 16 MHz and just couldn't keep up! All I needed to do was add a delay and now it works!